# How to activate a specific worksheet in different worksheet in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

In a sub i am parsing activesheet and creating a new sheet(in a new workbook),
After completion of this sub i need to activate the old sheet again
So i created

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
Analysis(sourceSheet)
```

In the next sub that will process this sheet, i sent the sourceSheet as variable

```
Public Sub Analysis(sourceSheet As Worksheet)
Set ActiveSheet = sourceSheet
```

It throws runtime error 438

How can i make the old sheet as active again? after creating new workbook using the parent sub

Comment: Since you're already declaring a worksheet variable for your sheet, I'd suggest reworking your code to avoid using `Acitve*` at all. It will help avoid all kinds of mistakes as your code gets more complex and you lose track of which sheet is currently active. Doing so is very straight forward, and doesn't take much time or effort for the potential reward.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can actually set `ActiveWorksheet`, as that is read-only.

I think instead of:

```
Set ActiveSheet = sourceSheet
```

You want:

```
sourceSheet.Activate
```